# Convert D3 to Angular component

Tags: angular, d3.js

I have this done now. How I can have it as Angular Component?? Here is a repo for that `https://github.com/bastiankhalil/line-chart-D3`
The problem in the function `tick()` which is should be called recursively.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
</style>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.js"></script>
<script>
var n = 40,
    random = d3.randomNormal(0, .2),
    data = d3.range(n).map(random);

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, n - 1])
    .range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([-1, 1])
    .range([height, 0]);

var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d, i) { return x(i); })
    .y(function(d, i) { return y(d); });

g.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
    
g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
g.append("g")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
  .append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line")
  .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .on("start", tick);


function tick() {

  data.push(random());
  // Redraw the line.
  d3.select(this)
      .attr("d", line)
      .attr("transform", null);
  // Slide it to the left.
  d3.active(this)
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(-1) + ",0)")
    .transition()
      .on("start", tick);
  data.shift();
}
</script>
```

Comment: I have seen some answered but they are very old and not in typescript.

Comment: I don't exactly know how to do it, I usually redreaw the whole new path. If you have an old example available, I can help you convert it.

Comment: @HuguesStefanski I have added a new code. However, it is pure. how can I have it as an Angular component? the syntax is really weird for me.

Comment: Do you maybe have a github repo with the complete code? It would make things easier, and allow for code sharing and iterations, as I don't think I'll be able to provide a solution in one shot.

Comment: @HuguesStefanski here a repo:  https://github.com/bastiankhalil/line-chart-D3

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work, full code available [here](https://github.com/Ledragon/line-chart-D3).

To get the code working, I had to do different things.

### Package

Install the full d3 package and import it. For some reason, Webpack does not catch that `transition` needs to be bundled

### `this` and `tick` function context

For the `tick` function to work, I had to jump though a few hoops.
First, the tick function has to be rebound in the component constructor to get the correct context:

```
constructor() {
   this.tick = this.tick.bind(this);
}
```

Then, in the update/transition phase, I had to capture the actual component before handling the `on` callback:

```
const self = this;
g.append('g')
  .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)')
  .append('path')
  .datum(this.data)
  .attr('class', 'line')
  .attr('d', this.theLine)
  .transition()
  .duration(500)
  .ease(d3.easeLinear)
  .on('start', function (d, i) {
    self.tick(this);
  });
```

Notice how I introduced the `self` variable before the callback, and use it to call the tick function with `this` as argument, and how I use an actual `function` and not a lambda/arrow function. In this case, `this` refers to the current selection (i.e. the path element).

Finally, I modified the `tick` function to accept the selected/transitioned element as an argument and apply the same trickery as the example you provided. Here again, I manually capture `this` in a `self` variable, use a `function` callback,and call `self.tick(this)`.

```
tick(sel: any) {
  const self = this;
  this.data.push(this.random());
  // Redraw the line.
  d3.select(sel)
    .attr('d', this.theLine)
    .attr('transform', null);
  // Slide it to the left.
  d3.active(sel)
    // .select('.line')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.x(-1) + ',0)')
    .transition()
    .on('start', function () { self.tick(this) });
  this.data.shift();
}
```

In the hope that this helps you :-). If something is unclear, let me know.

Comment: thank you very much for the help. The core problem that I can not import whole d3 library. Becuase we use the only modules we need. another point is that I can not use this syntax I should use arrow function instead. Can you transfer it that? I will push the changes I made soon.

Comment: As for the modules, you might check the webpack documentation to see if you can enforce the bundling of a module. As for not using a `function`, getting around it is gonna be hacky; I guess you could try and reselect `sel` in the `tick` function; however, I think transition returns a new instance of the object, so this might not work. Maybe suggest the person in charge of the style guide (as I guess this is the problem) to allow for exceptions?